# About 60 seconds GAE limit?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, task-queue

i want to send an email to 10,000 users but the problem is the process in the server could only last for 60 seconds.
could you please give an example code that count 100 million but it should be done by part. i need to determine how many seconds had past when it reach 59 seconds it should stop and continue to another call so that the 60 seconds limit of the GAE will not occur.
i dont want to use the cron jobs but task queue will do.

thanks for help..
i really appreciate it..

Comment: Why dont you want to use cron? it seems to fit perfectly?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? Couldn't you put your code in the backend service (that does not have the 60 seconds limit)?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to capture deadline error and queue new task

```
# get current count from task payload
try:
    # do something
    while True:
      # send email here
      count++;

except DeadlineExceededError:
     # roughly 1 second of before app engine kills this request
     # Queue new task with updated count
     taskqueue.add(queue_name='emailqueue',  ..., payload = count )

     # respond with ok so task won't be retried
     self.response.clear()
     self.response.set_status(200)
     self.response.out.write("OK")
```

In real app you want to pass the cursor to email list query to the next task

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Use Tasks to send a fixed number of emails (let's say 100). Then queue another task to continue where the first one left of. (Tasks are limited to 10 minutes).
2. Use MapReduce.
3. Use backends to send all the emails (no deadline limits)
4. You can also check for Deadline exceptions, but I'm not a fan of that method.

[This blog post](http://www.shiftedup.com/2015/03/12/deadline-errors-60-seconds-or-less-in-google-app-engine) talks a little bit more about deadline exceptions.